# Program to Connect to Specific Wireless Display Device

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd, miracast

I'm already aware that through the

```
"%windir%\explorer.exe ms-settings-connectabledevices:devicediscovery"
```

shortcut, I can open the "CONNECT" window which is good, and a step in the right direction, now I just want to know if there's a shortcut I can use to continue and connect to a specific device: either by name or by its ID. Either a shortcut like I have listed or some sort of .NET api I can program.